# How do I add parameter as a value in JPQL for INTERVAL from property file?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to send parameter from property file in **JPQL** using **@Query**

Suppose I have a query,

```
@Query(value= "Select * from myTable where id = ?1 AND last_modified_date between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ?2) AND NOW()", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyTableClass> getAllData(Long id, String stringSetFromPropertyFile);
```

Here the "`stringSetFromPropertyFile`" is sent from the **Service class**.
When I do the above thing it gives a query error where **?2 as a parameter** is not set **blank**.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Query(value= "Select * from myTable where id = ?1 AND last_modified_date between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ?2) AND NOW()",nativeQuery = true)
List<MyTableClass> getAllData(Long id, String stringSetFromPropertyFile);
```

Comment: I did add nativeQuery=true but also it didn't work for me.